# TS2394: This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature

Tags: typescript

I am fairly new to TS and learning function overloading. Somehow I am making a mistake that I can't seem to identify . The snippet is

> function parseCoordinate(obj : Coordinate): Coordinate; function
> parseCoordinate(str : String): Coordinate; function parseCoordinate(x:
> number, y: number): Coordinate; function parseCoordinate(arg1:
> unknown, arg2: unknown): Coordinate {
> let coord: Coordinate = {
> x: 0,
> y: 0
> }
>
> ```
> if (typeof arg1 === 'object') {
>     coord = {
>         ...(arg1 as Coordinate)
>     }
> } else {
>     coord = {
>         x: arg1 as number,
>         y: arg1 as number
>     }
> }
> return coord; }
> ```

I am told the titualr error for first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason is your implementation requires 2 parameters

```
parseCoordinate(arg1: unknown, arg2: unknown)
```

and 1 param overloads aren't compatible with 2 argument calls. to fix it make 2nd parameter optional by using `?`

```
parseCoordinate(arg1: unknown, arg2?: unknown)
```